# changed python.exe link in command Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I installed python 3.12.1 to DGB folder. But I want to change their location. But when I changed python 3.12.1 to different folder. Command Prompt deleted my python's path, Although it's also in my PC. I can't run python. I want to add my python's path to run python in cmd. What is my problem? How to fix it?

I tried to delete and install again but it installed into DGB folder by itself. I add python' link by 
`setx PATH "%PATH%;E:\Python\python.exe"` but it failed. I want when I write `py a.py` I can run `a.py` file, and I don't need to write `E:\Python\python.exe py a.py` to run `a.py` file.

Comment: You have already corrupted your Windows environment variables, and those should be fixed before you try to solve your other issues. If you require assistance with that, [Edit] your question with the content of the files `MyEnvars.log` and `SysEnvars.log`, on your Desktop, after running following two commands, in cmd.exe: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Export "HKCU\Environment" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\MyEnvars.log" /Y```, and ```%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Export "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\SysEnvars.log" /Y```.

Answer (score 0):

"py" is not the Python executable (as python.exe), but a launcher for Python. It should reside in the Windows directory and not need any path set, see also: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher

I'd suggest to reinstall Python to make sure the Python launcher is stored in the correct directory.